# protoc --go_opt=paths=source_relative vs --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative

Tags: go, protoc, grpc-go

I am having a hard time figuring out `protoc` command and go plugin.

What is the different between:

```
protoc \
   # Directory where you want the compiler to write your Go output.
   --go_out=.
   # vs ?
   --go_opt=paths=source_relative
   # vs ?
   --go-grpc_out=.
   # vs ?
   --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative
```

If `--go_opt` generate

- `<name>.pb.go` file

and `--go-grpc_opt` generate

- `<name>_grpc.pb.go` file

why even have `--go_out`?

Can you shed some light on protoc - the [doc](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#package) do not say anything about `--go-grpc_opt`?

And and `protoc -h` do not even list go as an OUT_DIR?

Note: I install using this [doc](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> why even have --go_out?

So, the thing to understand here is that gRPC is not the same as Protocol Buffers, gRPC uses Protocol Buffers but there are other frameworks that are using them as well. So we need to generate both.

Now, in order to generate the Protocol buffer related code, you need to use `--go_out` as you mentioned. but for the gRPC code you need to use `--go-grpc_out`.

> and --go-grpc_opt generate _grpc.pb.go file

No, `--go-grpc_out` does.

> Can you shade some light on protoc - the doc do not stay anything about --go-grpc_opt?

Then, before the generation of code you can pass some options and that's what `--go_opt` and `--go-grpc_opt` are for. The first one passes options for Protobuf generation and the second one for gRPC generation. Options are pretty obscure, and there is not official list of all of them, but you used `source_relative` (which tell protoc to use relative paths) for path and there is also the `module` option (which help protoc know the go module name to generate in proper folder)

> And and protoc -h do not even list go as an OUT_DIR?

And finally, protoc doesn't officially support Go as output, you need to install an external plugin and that's why `protoc -h` doesn't show `--go_out`. A related discussion can be found [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2963).

Answer (score 4):

**The** `protoc` compiler supports different flags or options and the flags you use on the command line decides where the generated go code will be placed.

The official [docs](https://protobuf.dev/reference/go/go-generated/#invocation) for these flags(atleast for `paths=source_relative` and `module=$PREFIX`) are not very clear and can be hard.

**paths=source_relative**

Here is what official docs says

> If the paths=source_relative flag is specified, the output file is
> placed in the same relative directory as the input file. For example,
> an input file protos/buzz.proto results in an output file at
> protos/buzz.pb.go.

The above statement might be confusing and hard to understand at first because
it is not giving complete context and folder layout of how the files are placed on the disk.

Here is how I understand it, when this flag is used the compiler generates the go code in the directory specified by
`--go_out` and ensures that directory tree structure of the generated go code
files matches the directory tree structure of *source* proto files. The word source
is important here because it can change based on the value of the `--proto_path`

Let's say we have the following directory structure

```bash
❯ tree
.
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── src
    └── protos
        ├── baz
        │   └── bar.proto
        └── foo.proto

4 directories, 4 files
```

Here is the general syntax of the `protoc` **command**

```
protoc --proto_path=<IMPORT_DIRECTORY> --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative <ONE_OR_MORE_SOURCE_PROTO_FILES>
```

Now lets consider the following examples

**# 1**

```
❯ protoc --proto_path=src/protos --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative foo.proto baz/bar.proto

❯ ls
baz       foo.pb.go go.mod    go.sum    src

~/development/personal/craftup/go-grpc/proto-buffers
❯ ls -R baz
bar.pb.go
```

In the above example we specified the import directory by setting `--proto_path=src/protos`
which makes the actual path for the source proto files to `foo.proto` and
`baz/bar.proto`, and hence the generated pb files were placed in the current
directory (`--go_out=.`) as `foo.pb.go` and `bar/baz.pb.go`.

Now let's change the `--proto_path` in the above command to `src` and see what happnes.

```
**# 2**

❯ protoc --proto_path=src --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative protos/foo.proto protos/bar/baz.proto

❯ ls -R src
protos

src/protos:
baz       foo.proto

src/protos/baz:
bar.proto
```

This time a new `protos` directory was created and the generated go files were placed
inside it, why ? Because this time when we changed the import path to `--proto-path=src`
the path for source proto files changed to `protos/foo.proto` and `protos/baz/bar.proto`.

**# 3**

Now let's finally mix `--go_out` flag here as well in here and see what happens

```
❯ mkdir out
❯ protoc --proto_path=src --go_out=out --go_opt=paths=source_relative protos/foo.proto protos/bar/baz.proto

❯ ls -R out
protos

out/protos:
baz       foo.pb.go

out/protos/baz:
bar.pb.go
```

This is exactly similar to last example except that we provided a custom directory to hold the generated code.

**module=$PREFIX**

> If the module=$PREFIX flag is specified, the output file is placed in
> a directory named after the Go package’s import path, but with the
> specified directory prefix removed from the output filename. For
> example, an input file protos/buzz.proto with a Go import path of
> example.com/project/protos/fizz and example.com/project specified as
> the module prefix results in an output file at protos/fizz/buzz.pb.go.
> Generating any Go packages outside the module path results in an
> error. This mode is useful for outputting generated files directly
> into a Go module.

Lets see this as well as in action, consider the following proto file at
location `src/baz/bar.proto` with following contents

```
syntax = "proto3";

package bar;

option go_package = "github.com/rbhanot/proto-buffers-practise/bar";

message GreetBar {
    string name = 1;
}
```

```
❯ protoc --proto_path=src --go_out=. --go_opt=module=github.com/rbhanot/proto-buffers-practise protos/foo.proto protos/baz/bar.proto
❯ ls
bar    foo    go.mod go.sum src

~/development/personal/craftup/go-grpc/proto-buffers
❯ ls -R foo bar
bar:
bar.pb.go

foo:
foo.pb.go
```

Lets see what happened here, the compiler removed the module prefix(`github.com/rbhanot/proto-buffers-practise`) from
the `go_package` specified in the proto file, then created the the package directories in the current directory(`--go_out=.`)
named after the remaining path in `go_package` option which were `foo` and `bar` and dumped the code files inside it.

Now lets change `go_package = "github.com/rbhanot/proto-buffers-practise/src";` and run the same command as above

```
❯ protoc --proto_path=src --go_out=out --go_opt=module=github.com/rbhanot/proto-buffers-practise protos/foo.proto protos/baz/bar.proto

❯ ls
go.mod go.sum out    src

~/development/personal/craftup/go-grpc/proto-buffers
❯ ls out/src
bar.pb.go foo.pb.go
```

This time we see that go code was generated inside the `out/src` directory.

I hope this makes things more clear (it atleast did for me) wrt to how these flags behave.